# jQuery classname validation not working for dynamically generated text fields

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am facing a problem with jQuery Validation to validate the ajax (dynamically) generated text fields...

**Here is the snippet of the HTML code**

```
         <form name="booking" id="booking" method="post" action="">
              <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>Mobile Number</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                <input  type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" class='form_mobile'/>
                </li>                    
                   <li>
                    <span>Number of male tickets</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                       <select name="male_qunatity" id="male_qunatity" >

                        </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

**Jquery validation script is here**

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

Here is the ajax call starts

 $('#male_qunatity').change(function() {

        var male_tickets = $(this).val();      
        var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
        var path = '<?php echo site_url() ?>';
        ajaxurl = path + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        var data = {
            action: 'get_quantity',
            qty: male_tickets,
            mobile: mobile
        };

          $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $('#m_attendees').html(response);
        });

     }); //END dropdown change event


       $("#booking").validate({
          });

      $('.form_mobile').each(function() {
      $(this).rules('add', {
        required:true,
        number:true,
      messages: {
        required:"Please enter a mobile number",
        number:"Only numbers allowed"
       }
     });
  });

  });//validation ends
```

**Here is the ajax code to text-boxes based on the count selected**

```
    $quantity=  $_REQUEST['qty'];
    $mobile=  $_REQUEST['mobile'];
    $pass = "<table>";
      for($i =0; $i<$quantity; $i++ ){
    $pass .= "<tr>
       <td>
      <input type='text'  id='mobile-".$i."' class='form_mobile' name='mmobile[]'>
      </td>
          </tr>";
       }
    $pass .= "</table>";
    echo $pass;
```

**FYI**:  The form validation is working fine for the form fields, except the dynamically created fields..

How to solve this one?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  However, if you're creating fields dynamically, then you would call `.rules('add')` ***AFTER*** the fields are dynamically created.

Comment: @sparky As i am calling the change event and ajax before the .rules('add').. Updated my question.

Comment: No, you're not really.  When `.rules('add')` is called the dynamic fields don't yet exist.

Comment: @Sparky I am wondered why the class name validation not working for the dynamic fields..Is there any mistakes in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  Since jQuery Validate depends on the `name` attribute, you'll need to alter your PHP to ensure that every `name` is unique.   Note the index, `$i`, added to the `name` attribute...

```
"... <input type=text  id='mobile-".$i."' name='mmobile[".$i."]' class='form_mobile'> ..."
```

(you're also missing quotes around `text`; should be `type='text'`)

2)  When creating fields dynamically, you would call `.rules('add')` ***AFTER*** the fields are dynamically created.  In your case, here...

```
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    $('#m_attendees').html(response);   // <- create the new fields
    $('.form_mobile').each(function() { // <- then dynamically add the rules
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required:true,
            number:true,
            messages: {
                required:"Please enter a mobile number",
                number:"Only numbers allowed"
            }
        });
    });
});
```

3)  `.validate()` is the initialization method for the plugin on your `form`.  Just call it once when the DOM loads.  *(`.validate()` does not get called repeatedly when the form is validated, because validation is automatic once the plugin is properly initialized.)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // <- DOM is ready

    $("#booking").validate({    // <- initialize plugin on your form
        // your options         // <- plugin options
    });

});
```

Comment: so where can i call the "$("#booking").validate({ });"  ???
If i add after $("#m_attendees").html(response) then it only validates after change event occurs..

Comment: @PHPCoder, There was nothing in my original answer saying to move `.validate()`.  See the code I posted.  You would call the `.validate()` method ONCE to initialize the plugin on your `form`.  You'd do that within the DOM ready event handler.  In other words, just leave it where you originally had it.

Comment: +1 Validation working now.. Thanks for your suggestions and quick response

Comment: @PHPCoder, you're welcome.  Also noticed you're missing the quotes around `text` in your HTML.  `input type='text'`